# HBase shell Crashes giving CMSIncrementalMode error

Tags: java, hbase

## When I run HBASe Shell on mac, I get the following error

> Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: Option UseConcMarkSweepGC was deprecated in version 9.0 and will likely be removed in a future release.
>   Unrecognized VM option 'CMSIncrementalMode'
>
> Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine.
>   Error: A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit.*

Comment: Sounds like you need to edit your HBase startup script to remove "CMSIncrementalMode" from wherever it launches Java.  SUGGESTIONS: Start with `conf/hbase-env.sh` (if you have one).  Otherwise, "grep" for the word "CMSIncrementalMode" in your HBase install directory until you find the culprit.

Comment: Many thanks.. It worked... but now I have started getting another error *$./bin/hbase shell*
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: Option UseConcMarkSweepGC was deprecated in version 9.0 and will likely be removed in a future release.
Error: Could not find or load main class Big
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Big